# C# PrincipalSearcher, returning AD groups for specific OU

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm having a bit of difficultly with this code, specifically with PrincipalSearcher. I'm trying to get a list of all the Groups associated with a specific OU.

I'm trying to just return "Security" groups under all Group Scopes, excluding distribution groups.

The issue I'm having is, it's returning these built-in groups in addition to the one's I'm intending to return.

HelpServicesGroup
TelnetClients
Administrators
Users
Guests
Print Operators
Backup Operators
Replicator
Remote Desktop Users
Network Configuration Operators
Performance Monitor Users
Performance Log Users
Distributed COM Users
Domain Computers
Domain Controllers
Schema Admins
Enterprise Admins
Cert Publishers
Domain Admins
Domain Users
Domain Guests
Group Policy Creator Owners
RAS and IAS Servers
Server Operators
Account Operators
Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access
Incoming Forest Trust Builders
Windows Authorization Access Group
Terminal Server License Servers
DnsAdmins
DnsUpdateProxy
IIS_WPG

I'm not sure if perhaps the scope is incorrect or maybe I'm missing some sort of filtering.

The relevant code segment:

```
    public static ArrayList GetAllGroups()
    {
        var myItems = new ArrayList();

        var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"MyOU");

        // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
        var qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

        // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
        var srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

        // find all matches
        foreach (Principal found in srch.FindAll())
        {
            var foundGroup = found as GroupPrincipal;

            if (foundGroup != null)
            {
                myItems.Add(foundGroup.Name);
            }
        }
        return myItems;
    }
```

How do I get this to exclude the built-in groups?

Any assistance with this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things:

1. there are no groups *associated* with an OU - an OU is a **container** which **contains** users, computers, groups etc. (like a directory that contains files). Is that what you mean? You want to enumerate the group **contained** inside a given OU??
2. if so: you're not calling the constructor for the `PrincipalContext` properly. If you check the [MSDN documentation on `PrincipalContext` constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.aspx), you'll see that the one you're using is the one with a `ContextType` and a `name` which stands for the **domain name** of the context you want to bind to:

   ```
   var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"MyOU");
   ```

   This binds to the `MyOU` domain - and it binds right at the root of that domain tree.

What you're probably looking for is the constructor with three parameters - a `ContextType` and **two strings** - the first one being the domain name as above, and the second one being the start location of your search. So change your `PrincipalContext` construction to:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN", "OU=MyOU");
```

and then search again - **now** you should get only groups that are **contained** inside the `OU=MyOU` container.

Comment: Marc, Thank you kindly for that explanation I understand the issue now.

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

```
    var myItems = new ArrayList();

    var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName, "OU=Groups,DC=Domain,DC=Com");

    // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal  
    var qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

    // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal     
    var srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

    // find all matches 
    foreach (Principal found in srch.FindAll())
    {
        var foundGroup = found as GroupPrincipal;

        if (foundGroup != null && foundGroup.IsSecurityGroup == true)
        {
            myItems.Add(foundGroup.Name);
        }
    }
```

PrincipalContext requires contextType, Domain and the Container's DN (if you just want to search a container).

foundGroup != null && foundGroup.IsSecurityGroup == true will return all security groups. Which is what you want.

You could also use GroupScope to refine things if you like:

foundGroup != null && foundGroup.GroupScope == GroupScope.Global will narrow the scope to global groups.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Daro, thank you for this alteration to the code, I've implemented a different routine based on the information from Marc S.